# Sqlalchemy cannot determine dialect for firebird

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, firebird

I'm attempting to convert a Firebird database to SQL, and my first goal is to read in the database via SQLAlchemy. It looks like I have all the libraries I need, but when I attempt the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.firebird.base import dialect

engine = create_engine('firebird+fdb://localhost/C:/Temp/TEST.GDB')
```

I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine dialect for 'firebird+fdb'.

Comment: Which version of SQLAlchemy are you using? your example runs well for me. I'm on 0.8.2

Comment: I'm using version 0.7.11

Comment: Humm, maybe thats the problem. Do you have any problems trying with `create_engine('firebird://localhost/C:/Temp/TEST.GDB')`?

Comment: I get this instead:
> ImportError: No module named kinterbasdb

I've tried updating my sqlalchemy to 8.2, but then I get
> ImportError: No module named langhelpers
if I try to run anything in sqlalchemy.

Comment: Well, first you need to install kinterbasdb as it provides access to firebird databases, also you need to check the dependencies of SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 1):

FDB support has been added in SQLAlchemy version 0.8:

> New in version 0.8: - Support for the fdb Firebird driver.

Answer (score 1):

first of all install module:

```
pip install sqlalchemy-firebird
```

then use:

```
engine = create_engine('firebird://localhost/C:/Temp/TEST.GDB')
```

without "+fdb"

instead of:
engine = create_engine('firebird+fdb://localhost/C:/Temp/TEST.GDB')

that worked for me

Also you can use:
df = pd.DataFrame(engine.connect().execute(text(sql)))